# view images separated by commas to php

Tags: php, html

view images separated by commas, I would please need your help

from the database and with a select I extract the images

`GROUP_CONCAT (DISTINCT (CONCAT ('https: //', IFNULL (conf.value, 'undefined_domain')), '/ img / p /', IF (CHAR_LENGTH (pi.id_image)> = 5, CONCAT (SUBSTRING (pi. id_image, -5, 1), '/'), ''), IF (CHAR_LENGTH (pi.id_image)> = 4, CONCAT (SUBSTRING (pi.id_image, -4, 1), '/'), ''), IF (CHAR_LENGTH (pi.id_image)> = 3, CONCAT (SUBSTRING (pi.id_image, -3, 1), '/'), ''), IF (CHAR_LENGTH (pi.id_image)> = 2, CONCAT (SUBSTRING (pi.id_image, -2, 1), '/'), ''), IF (CHAR_LENGTH (pi.id_image)> = 1, CONCAT (SUBSTRING (pi.id_image, -1, 1), '/'), ''), pi.id_image, '. jpg')) SEPARATOR '') AS 'images',`

i would like to show the 5 images in my template which has this php code

```
<? php
<img src = 'image one here'>
</div>
<div class = 'gallery-image'>
<img src = 'image two here'>
</div>
<div class = 'gallery-image'>
<img src = 'image three here'>
</div>
<div class = 'gallery-image'>
<img src = 'image four here'>
</div>
<div class = 'gallery-image'>
<img src = 'image five here' '>
</div>?>
```

I don't know how to do it, can you please help me?

Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to select there from the database? Why not doing it row by row?

Comment: i extract product images from prestashop and i can't do it line by line

Comment: Why do you pack them together if you need them to be separate? (You have `explode()` anyway.)

Comment: I would need an example on how to use explode and make img display as above please

Comment: from the select it extracts the urls and I have to insert them in the single <img src = 'image one here'>, <img src = 'image two here'> etc. etc.